# Explanation needed for this weird polymorphic behavior

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I was learning about polymorphism and tried some basic stuffs.In the following code, I have a virtual function `display()` in base class `Animal`.I made two derived classes, `Dog` that inherited from `Animal` and `Tommy` that inherited from `Dog`. The `display()` function was overridden in one of the derived class only(`Tommy` class in the following code).

In the `main()` function, I pointed to the derived objects through the base class pointer.I thought the following snippet would give me an error.

```
ptr = &dog;
ptr->display();
```

But, it ended up calling the `display()` of the parent class of `Dog`(i,e. `Animal`).Out of curiosity,I removed `display()` function in other derived classes and checked the output but I get the same behavior, always ends up calling the `display()` of the parent class.I don't know why this is happening.I think I am missing something here.Please help.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Animal
    {
        protected:
            string name;
        public:
            Animal(string nam):name(nam){}

            virtual void display()const {cout<<"Base class.\n";}

        };

    class Dog : public Animal
    {
        public:
        Dog(string nam):Animal(nam){}

        };

    class Tommy : public Dog
    {
        public:
        Tommy(string nam):Dog(nam){}

        void display()const{cout<<"i am  "<<name<<endl;}
        };

    int main()
    {
        Animal *ptr;
        Dog dog("trace");
        Tommy tom("tommy");

        ptr = &dog;
        ptr->display();

        ptr = &tom;
        ptr->display();


        return 0;
        }
```

The output was:

```
Base class.
i am  tommy
```

Comment: That is the way it is designed to work. I am not sure what more can be added. Or are you asking *why* it was designed that way?

Comment: *I made two derived classes, `Dog` that inherited from `Animal` and `Tommy` that inherited from `Dog.`* - That sounds wrong. Shouldn't `Tommy` be an **object** of type `Dog`? Is `Tommy` a dog race? Can you raise a horde of "tommies"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah, you have a point but I just wanted to make 3-4 derived classes to play around with and I ran out of class names in the end so I picked Tommy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, it ended up calling the display() of the parent class of Dog(i,e. Animal).

This is totally expected behaviour as you did not overwrite virtual function `display` in your derived class `Dog`.

In order to have specific behaviour for the derived class, you must implement the non-pure virtual function `display`. You already have  implementation for that function in the `Tommy` class, but no such implementation in the `Dog` class.

Comment: So is it a compulsion that I must override a virtual function even if its not pure?

Comment: No, of course not. Your example shows that you *don't* have to override it.

Comment: You must implement pure virtual function in derived class. For non-pure virtual function there is no such compulsory as the derived class can use the default implementation of base class.

Comment: @artm: You do not need to implement a pure virtual function in a derived class. The derived class can itself remain abstract. But at same point in the class hierarchy, you will want to arrive at a concrete class, and then the pure virtual function must be implemented.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes I do mean the final leaf class in the inheritance hierarchy must implement pure virtual function - as you said middle derived classes in the hierarchy can still be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The first time a value is displayed, it is of type Dog. Dog has no redefinition of display, it uses the one from Animal because it inherits this function.

The second time a value is displayed, it is of type Tommy. Tommy has a redefinition of the display function, which is "i am tommy". It will show this string because it redefines this virtual function.

That's due to the fact that Tommy is an Animal because Tommy inherits Dog which inherits Animal. Think of it this way : every Tommy is an Animal, but not every Animal is a Tommy nor a Dog.

Virtual is a keyword in C++ which means a function can be redefined in children classes.

EDIT : Just a clarification as to what are pure virtual functions and virtual functions. A pure virtual function states that the functions NEEDS to be redefined in his children classes or it won't compile (i.e. there's no implementation in the base class for this function). A virtual function states that it CAN BE redefined in his children classes (it has an implementation in the base class). In this example, display is a virtual function, not a pure one.